# Why is scope.$digest() necessary inside $document.keydown()?

Tags: angularjs

I have a slide deck service:

```
app.factory('slideDeckService', function () {
    var slideDeck = new SlideDeck();

    return {
      currentPosition: 0,
      ...

      back: function () { // Back to last slide
        if(this.currentPosition > 0) {
          this.currentPosition--;
        }
      },

      forward: function () { // Advance to next slide
        if(this.currentPosition < slideDeck.slides.length - 1) {
          this.currentPosition++;
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

I inject the service into this directive:

```
app.directive('coreSlides', [ 
    'slideDeckService', 
    '$document',
    '$log',

    function(slideDeckService, $document, $log) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'views/partials/slides-template.html',
        transclude: true,

        controller: function ($scope) {
          $document.keydown(function(event) {
            var LEFT_ARROW = 37, RIGHT_ARROW = 39;

            if(event.keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
              slideDeckService.forward();
            }
            else if(event.keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
              slideDeckService.back();
            }
          });

          $scope.$watch(
            function () { return slideDeckService.currentPosition; },

            function(newValue, oldValue) {
              $log.info('new value: ' + newValue + ', 
                         old value: ' + oldValue);
            });
        },

        link: function (scope, el, attrs) { ... }
     }
  }]);
```

But that does not work. For the $scope.$watch() to work I have to explicitly invoke $scope.$digest(), as follows:

```
$document.keydown(function(event) {
  var LEFT_ARROW = 37, RIGHT_ARROW = 39;
  var forward = event.keyCode != 37;  // left arrow goes back

  if(event.keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
    slideDeckService.forward();
    $scope.$digest();  // Why is this necessary?
  }
  else if(event.keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    slideDeckService.back();
    $scope.$digest(); // Why is this necessary?
  }
  ...
});
```

I was under the impression that injected objects like $document exist primarily to run the $digest() method as necessary. I expected $document.keydown() to invoke $scope.$digest() automatically when it was done. Inside of $document.keydown() am I not *in the Angular realm*? If I was using the plain old document object, I would expect to have to invoke $digest(), but I don't expect that with $document.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on why the explicit call to $scope.$digest() is necessary in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24document) states that `$document` is just a JQuery/JQLite wrapper, you're not in a $digest-loop when the user triggers an event, and there's nothing automatic that will cause a loop to happen either.

Angular's own built-in directives that trigger on user events also has to trigger $digest-loops [via $apply](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L50).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I hate to nitpick, however, but the word "just" is not in the documentation. It would be nice if the documentation mentioned the fact that you're not in a digest loop for the unaware, instead of a terse one-liner that leaves you guessing. How is one supposed to know whether or not you're in a digest loop when using any of Angular's services? Google should hire a decent tech writer to work on Angular's docs. The documentation is absolutely abysmal, IMHO.

Comment: I'll agree that the documentation isn't very good. I added the word "just" to emphasize that `$document` simply wraps `window.document` and nothing more, i.e. "just a wrapper". I also had problems telling what's inside a $digest context or not when I was starting out with Angular, but after 2 years of using it, I never really think about it. Basically. In this case you're outside because `keydown` adds a DOM event listener and the DOM event loop is separate from the $digest loop. There's a nice drawing of it somewhere in the docs, I'll try to find it for you.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop, your keydown DOM event is in the Native/Javascript context, someone needs to call `$apply` or `$digest` to enter the Angular context. Like I mentioned, this is also true for Angular's own built-ins. I agree it's hard to know this offhand without having seen it, but that doesn't change the reason for why its needed.