# Change in $document.on('click') not reflected in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, dom-events

I have an angular directive `ngx-notifications`, it sits inside a controller `MenuBarController`.

**View**

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="MenuBarController">
 ...
  <span ng-click="ShowNotifications()">click me</span>
  <div ng-show="NotificationsVisible" ngx-notifications="NotificationsVisible">
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.NotificationsVisible = false;

function ShowNotifications(){
  $scope.NotificationsVisible = !$scope.NotificationsVisible;
}


setInterval(function(){
  console.log($scope.NotificationsVisible);
},1000);
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('app').directive('ngxNotifications', NotificationsDirective);

NotificationsDirective.$inject = ['$document'];
function NotificationsDirective($document) {

  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: false,
    link: function ($scope, $elem, $attr) {
      var key = $attr.ngxNotifications;

      $document.on("click",function ($e) {
        if(!$elem[0].contains($e.target)){
          console.log($scope,key); // logs correct scope and key
          //neither of the two following lines are reflected in the view
          $scope[key] = false;
          $scope.NotificationsVisible = false;

        }
      });

    }
  }
}
```

The `span[ng-click]` toggles the visibility of my notification box, but for some reason when my `directive` changes it via `$document.on('click')` angular doesn't pick up the change, despite the fact that my `setTimeout` in the `controller` shows that the value HAS changed. Why is this?

I can't create a separate scope between my controller and my directive, I just need to add this extra functionality.

Comment: If you see this question, the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24521300/why-is-scope-digest-necessary-inside-document-keydown somewhat answers what is happening (I can't flag as duplicate because the other answer hasn't been accepted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, for some reason the `$document::on` method is not part of the angular digest, adding `$scope.$apply` worked, but this doesn't really make sense (I never left angular code to change the model):

```
$document.bind("click",function ($e) {
  if($scope[key] && !$elem[0].contains($e.target)){
    $scope.$apply(function () {
      $scope[key] = false;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I think your original solution does not work because of the $document.bind. Its not part of the angular digest loop. You then force it with the $scope.apply().

Comment: yea i read that after posting (did a quick google once i figured out what was going on). This is unfortunate, I kind of expect native angular code to operate in a digest loop